# Controlling mouse pointer with keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

How can I control the mouse pointer with keyboard (e.g. with arrow keys) on Windows OS?

Some computers I use have mice with bad sensitivity, so I sometimes need to have more precise mouse controls.

Note: I'm using Windows 7 personally but the computers I handle have different versions of Windows (2000, XP, Vista).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify which version of Windows you're using.

It should be possible with MouseKeys, one of the accessibility features of Windows. See more explanation [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775624(WS.10).aspx).

It's supported in Windows [2000](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windows2000/mousekeys.aspx), [XP](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/mousekeys.aspx), [Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/mousekeys.aspx) and [7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer).

Comment: Thanks Snark, that's what I need. Please add MouseKeys shortcut to your answer (Alt+Shift+NumLock) for those who want to easily activate it.