# How to move the cursor with the keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, mouse-cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Controlling mouse pointer with keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/77277/controlling-mouse-pointer-with-keyboard)

I remember that I did it once, but I totally forgot (the truth is that I don't know how I did it).

I here asking how to move the cursor with the keyboard (the arrow keys) on Windows 7?

Comment: Do you specifically need it to be the arrow keys? The standard feature built into Windows (Mouse Keys) uses the number pad. It can normally be enabled using the keyboard shortcut **[ALT] + [LEFT SHIFT] + [NUM LOCK]** or through **Control Panel -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the mouse easier to use**

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/access_mousekeys_howtomove.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your point is. Also, that document is for Windows XP and there have been some changes to how it works since then - you specifically mentioned that you were using Windows 7.