# Make the mouse pointer jump to a link location, on the screen, via keyboard in web browser

Tags: keyboard, browser, mouse, links

Isn't there any way to make the mouse pointer jump to a link location, on the screen , via keyboard.
I needed that feature sometimes , to see brief information about someone in Facebook , by moving the pointer over a name.

`Vimium` in `chrome` looks promising , but does'nt seem to have that feature.

Comment: Which OS? http://superuser.com/questions/77277/controlling-mouse-pointer-with-keyboard?rq=1  In windows there is also the TAB method for hopping from link to link, this does not move the actual mouse so it does not do a "hover".

Comment: I want the pointer to jump to a link location, on the screen , via keyboard, like I do in `vimium` to click on a link(Pressing <kbd>F</kbd> and then pressing certain keys).

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Windows PC, you can use the [Mouse Keys feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer).

With Mouse Keys, you can use the numeric keypad on your keyboard—instead of the mouse—to move the pointer.

Comment: No, I used mouse keys.I've actually wanted the pointer to jump to the location where the link is , by pressing keys , like I use in `vimium` to click on a link(Pressing <kbd>F</kbd> and then pressing certain keys).